# Failed to get request token on Android M running Devices

Tags: twitter, twitter-fabric

Twitter login failed in Android 6.0 preview devices. Its working fine on all other devices.

Below code is used to initialize fabric with twitter.

TWITTER_ KEY and TWITTER_SECRET keys were obtained from twitter app settings.

```
    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
```

Here is the error log i got during login using TwitterApiClient.

```
  08-31 07:52:09.988 4692-4692/? E/Twitter: Failed to get request token
  08-31 07:52:09.988 4692-4692/? E/Twitter: com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException: 401 Authorization Required
  08-31 07:52:09.988 4692-4692/? E/Twitter: at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:383)
  08-31 07:52:09.988 4692-4692/? E/Twitter: at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
  08-31 07:52:09.988 4692-4692/? E/Twitter: at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
  08-31 07:52:09.988 4692-4692/? E/Twitter: at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
  08-31 07:52:09.988 4692-4692/? E/Twitter: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
  08-31 07:52:09.988 4692-4692/? E/Twitter: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
  08-31 07:52:09.988 4692-4692/? E/Twitter: at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
  08-31 07:52:09.988 4692-4692/? E/Twitter: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
  08-31 07:52:10.000 4692-4692/? E/Twitter: Authorization completed with an error
  08-31 07:52:10.000 4692-4692/? E/Twitter: com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Failed to get request token
  08-31 07:52:10.000 4692-4692/? E/Twitter: at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthController$1.failure(OAuthController.java:95)
  08-31 07:52:10.000 4692-4692/? E/Twitter: at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.oauth.OAuth1aService$1.failure(OAuth1aService.java:215)
  08-31 07:52:10.000 4692-4692/? E/Twitter: at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.failure(Callback.java:45)
  08-31 07:52:10.000 4692-4692/? E/Twitter: at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$2.run(CallbackRunnable.java:53)
  08-31 07:52:10.000 4692-4692/? E/Twitter: at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  08-31 07:52:10.000 4692-4692/? E/Twitter: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  08-31 07:52:10.000 4692-4692/? E/Twitter: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  08-31 07:52:10.000 4692-4692/? E/Twitter: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
  08-31 07:52:10.000 4692-4692/? E/Twitter: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  08-31 07:52:10.000 4692-4692/? E/Twitter: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
  08-31 07:52:10.000 4692-4692/? E/Twitter: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: somethimes in developer console r u authenticate wia email is these confirm from your side ?? and check both virtual and real device...!!!

Answer (score 31):

Before this solution, I tried a **valid url** (even `google.com`). But, in my case, it did not work.

I then found this solution, which worked well for me:

**Step 1:** Go to your twitter app's settings by logging in at https://apps.twitter.com/ and selecting the **Settings** tab, then add `twittersdk://` as a callback url. (I found it in lib class.)

**Step 2:** Save your update.

**Step 3:** Try your app again.

Comment: Please don't keep posting the same answer in multiple old questions. Flag as duplicate if you think they are.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30511345/twitter-failed-to-get-request-token/50907869#50907869

Comment: The intention was to allow user to get answer even if the user visit this post.

Comment: @Shree and the question are different but solution are same for current scenario. But in future it can be a different

Comment: @Moinkhan Thank you

Comment: @Moinkhan thks you

Comment: Thanks @Moinkhan

Answer (score 29):

Here are the things you need to do

Twitter dev account->setting->callBack url

and then if you are doing for the android (means login using for android devices )

> twittersdk://
>   (add this in callback)

if you are doing for the iOS (means login using for apple devices )

> twitterkit-CONSUMERKEY://
>   (add this in callback)

and hit update settings button 
it will work :)

Answer (score 9):

I have same problem and solved. In my case i need to set callback url in twitter dev account.

> Twitter dev account->setting->callBack url(set any valid url like
>   www.google.com)

Comment: I have already did it.Igot below error:  com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Failed to get request token
The reason for this error is i dont have twitter app installed.If i do then it works fine
What should i have to do?

Comment: @Rajat Same Problem here and that to  SDK.M Devices only........... please anybody help..........

Answer (score 7):

this is the best solution when twitter auth not working without app. i tried with valid firebase auth callback url but not working and i also search this problem a lot but not getting the exact solution, **@Moinkhan** solution worked for me and save my time, thanks to **@Moinkhan**, it works

Before this solution i tried valid url and even google.com too. But for my case it was not working.

i found below solution and it work well for me.

Step 1: go to your twitter app setting https://apps.twitter.com/ >> Tab settings >> Fill this text "twittersdk://" to your callback url field( i found it in lib class)

Step 2: Save your update

Step 3: check out your app again

Comment: You saved my day. I wonder this is not working without the "twittersdk://"? Are you using Firebase UI?

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue(just moments back).


Go to [Twitter Application Management](https://apps.twitter.com/) ->

Click on the 'app' on which you are currently working ->

Click on 'Settings' tab ->

1) **Callback URL**: Insert any valid url(like homepage of your website) 

2) **Enable Callback Locking (It is recommended to enable callback locking to ensure apps cannot overwrite the callback url)**: Verify that it is **unchecked**

> Twitter Kit tries to use a **webview** if the *twitter app* is **not** found.
>   
> The *webview part of Twitter kit* needs to **override** the **callback url**. 
>   
>   
> Info about **Callback Url** field clearly states: *To restrict your application from using callbacks, leave this field blank.*
>   
> So, we need to write down any valid url :)

Reference:

**Personal experience obtained moments back :P**

[Failed to get request token](https://twittercommunity.com/t/failed-to-get-request-token/52996/2#post_7)

Answer (score 1):

After going through a lot of solutions, one that worked for me is 
just add - **twittersdk://** as one more callback URL in the setting section of your twitter app.

Answer (score 0):

Create your Your Access Token in Key and Access Token tab

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on iOS, and found a hint [here](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/1310#issuecomment-397343370):
Apparently, it is now required to set the Callback URL to

`http://twitter-oauth.callback`

Sind I did so, the login works again.

Answer (score -1):

1. Make sure your Callback Urls is inputted.
2. Make sure Twitter app is installed on your device(Android, iOS)

Hope this help. It work well for me (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/79450).

Comment: Twitter mustn't be installed on the device, it will open web view instead