# Twitter login failure when there is no app in android

Tags: android, twitter

Twitter login is failing when there is no twitter app in my android device.
My error log is given below

> 11-24 09:47:54.390 31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter: Invalid
>   json:  11-24 09:47:54.390
>   31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter:  11-24 09:47:54.390
>   31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter:   Desktop applications
>   only support the oauth_callback value 'oob' 11-24 09:47:54.390
>   31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter:
>   /oauth/request_token 11-24 09:47:54.390
>   31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter:  11-24 09:47:54.390
>   **31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter: Failed to get request token
>   11-24 09:47:54.390 31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter:
>   com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException: 401 Authorization
>   Required 11-24 09:47:54.390 31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter:
>
>   at
>   retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:383)**
>   11-24 09:47:54.390 31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter:     at
>   retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
>   11-24 09:47:54.390 31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter:     at
>   retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
>   11-24 09:47:54.390 31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter:     at
>   retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42) 11-24
>   09:47:54.390 31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   11-24 09:47:54.390 31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   11-24 09:47:54.390 31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter:     at
>   retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142) 11-24
>   09:47:54.390 31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter:     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 11-24 09:47:54.417
>   **> 31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter: Authorization completed with
>   an error 11-24 09:47:54.417 31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter:
>   com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Failed to get
>   request token 11-24 09:47:54.417 31738-31738/com.nighthub.app
>   E/Twitter:     at
>   com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthController$1.failure(OAuthController.java:95)**
>   11-24 09:47:54.417 31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter:     at
>   com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.oauth.OAuth1aService$1.failure(OAuth1aService.java:215)
>   11-24 09:47:54.417 31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter:     at
>   com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.failure(Callback.java:45) 11-24
>   09:47:54.417 31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter:     at
>   retrofit.CallbackRunnable$2.run(CallbackRunnable.java:53) 11-24
>   09:47:54.417 31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter:     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 11-24 09:47:54.417
>   31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 11-24 09:47:54.417
>   31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 11-24 09:47:54.417
>   31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312) 11-24
>   09:47:54.417 31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 11-24 09:47:54.417
>   31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 11-24 09:47:54.417
>   31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
>   11-24 09:47:54.417 31738-31738/com.nighthub.app E/Twitter:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)

Comment: check application in developer console .. that is complete or not with email authenticate , permission

Comment: it works perfect when app is present.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you solve this?

Comment: Create your Your Access Token in Key and Access Token tab

Answer (score 1):

https://apps.twitter.com/

select your app
In Setting tab
Enter some url in Callback URL (any valid url is ok, since the Twitter Kit will override it)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. I solved it by changing my twitter app settings.

1. Visit  https://apps.twitter.com/
2. Select your App
3. Go to settings
4. Uncheck 'Enable Callback Locking (It is recommended to enable callback locking to ensure apps cannot overwrite the callback url)'
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution which you guys are looking for I faced the same problem and I solved it like this and it is according to twitter SDK https://stackoverflow.com/a/51982842/3260396

Answer (score 0):

It happen when you device does not install twitter app. so its open webview..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41756828/4388036

I have same problem and solved. In my case i need to set callback url in twitter dev account.

> Twitter dev account->setting->callBack url(set any valid url like
>   www.google.com)